# Set up connection to VPN on Amazon Lightsail app

Tags: django, linux, command-line, vpn, amazon-lightsail

I've got an server on AWS using Lightsail that uses Linux/Django OS/app combination. I need to use the Django framework to create a function that will take requests coming into the server, and forward them on to another API. This API is only accessible through a VPN.

I believe that by just connecting my OS to the VPN any requests my Django app sends should go through the VPN (in theory, please correct me if I'm wrong), however I am unsure how to connect to the VPN using just the Linux command line. I have the server name, a username and password, which I can connect to fine on my Windows machine by just adding a VPN connection.

Is anyone able to advise if it is possible to connect this OS provided by Amazon Lightsail to a VPN, and if so how to do so in order for me to able to route HTTPS requests to the API behind a VPN!

Thanks, hopefully I'm posting this in the right place!

Comment: Which version of Linux did you choose, what VPN is running on the receiving end?

Comment: Hi tink, I believe it's Linux version 4.19, and the VPN should be PPTP.

Comment: I have made some progress, output of my connection details using nmcli: https://pastebin.com/pRh7U4Ec. I've replaced the server name with servername.com. When trying to connect I get "Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection."

The only thing I can think of is that I haven't specified the VPN name properly